# Using parentheses to group condition values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this is a really basic question, however, I'm only just learning SQL in a practical sense.
So I'm looking to get the sum total of some of our subscriptions, between two specific dates in time. I use the following query below:

```
FROM orders o
WHERE o.created_at BETWEEN '2021-06-01' AND '2021-08-31'
 AND o.subscription_id = ('1567')
 ;
```

However, I need to find the combined total of over 100 subscriptions and I don't want to do it manually, and I know there is a way of using the brackets at
`o.subscription_id` however, I cannot quite remember how to do nor, phrase it for into Google.

Thanks in advance everyone

Comment: You are looking for `IN`, not `=`.

Comment: You can add more codes to search for using `IN` as in: `o.subscription_id in ('1567', '1234', '5678')`.

Comment: If these subscriptions are related in a way which can be queried:  `o.subscription_id IN (SELECT subscription_id FROM ... etc)`